Is "winning" used in the past tense?
I have the sentence:

It was academy award nominated actor, academy award nominated director, academy award winning writer Orson Welles.

As a native speaker, that feels correct, but it seems that the tenses don't match for 'award nominated' and 'award winning'.
Is there some way the tense of winning is matching, or something implicit I'm missing or a mistake with this sentence?

I would use "winning" for a book and "winner" for the author.

Winner is a noun, winning is an adjective though right? I'm using it an adjective to modify the noun author.

The adjectival participle "winning" doesn't have a "tense" in such contexts. I can say my dead grandmother had a winning smile, and I might hope my as-yet-unborn daughter will have a winning smile. Note that in the above example, winning modifies award - it's the two-word "adjectival phrase" award-winning that modifies author.

Welles was nominated by someone else but won himself, so you wouldn't expect the same verb form to be used for both. Past participle is passive, present participle is active. But "award-winning" is such a common phrase, it's a mistake to look too deeply into grammar.

There are similar questions already but not sure if there's an exact match. For instance, this, etc

"Academy Award" is treated as one word, it descibes a single, specific item, aka an "Oscar" from the Academy of Motion Picture Arts and Sciences. In the newspaper aticle, it SHOULD'VE BEEN HYPHENATED but the proofers, if any, missed it.

Also consider My grandmother was a fun-loving person. I hope my daughter will be a fun-loving person. And see Present Participle(adjective) vs Progressive tense

The 'always hyphenate compound premodifiers' rule is nowadays relaxed, the hyphen being seen as unnecessary to point out that examples like  " 'Academy Award' is treated as one word". Many use the '... where not to hyphenate would lead to confusion' caveat, and here, as you imply, there is negligible doubt about the cohesiveness of 'Academy Award'. Results from reasonable-looking articles on the internet divide almost equally between 'Academy Award-winning' and 'Academy Award winning'.

@EdwinAshworth It's not so much a matter of the hyphens being strictly necessary, as being helpful: making the sentence easier to parse and understand.  They can resolve ambiguity in some cases, but even in others they can help to clarify and avoid garden-path sentences.  And it's simpler all round if you always use them.  After all, (most) people don't drop letters, spaces, or words simply because it's possible to decipher the sentence without them; if we want people to read what we write, it benefits us to make it as easy to read as possible!

@gidds Note Chris V's accepted answer here. There are other threads, and – I believe – articles in the literature,  with the same advice . The non-dropping of hyphens where not strictly necessary for clarity  is certainly not considered the better choice by a lot of practised Anglophones, and the counter-argument is for minimal punctuation and decluttering.

I read winning as part of the phrase Academy Award-winning, that is, the participle forms an adjective phrase modifying writer. It denotes someone who has won the award, in the same sense that we could say, "His work was the winning choice." Winning isn't in past tense even if the award happened in the past. It instead denotes having won at any previous time.
The usage may be idiomatic to winning and nominated, as a kind of marketing buzz. Usages with similar verbs may sound odd to the ear even if they make literal sense, e.g.,

(x) Award-obtaining writer


(x) Award-receiving writer


(x) Award-achieving writer

Similarly, winning may pair with a small number of noun phrases related to something won: award-winning (4803 entries in the Corpus of Contemporary American English), prize-winning (1755 entries in COCA), game-winning (1064 entries in COCA), and similar, not to mention proper noun phrases like Academy Awards, Stanley Cup, and so on. The usage may also be recent; early hits for the phrase tend to show up in magazine ads, perhaps as a promotional turn of phrase. Here is an example from the March 1923 issue of Good Housekeeping, via Google Books:


Participles are not tensed.
You have a passive voice “passive participle” and an active voice “active participle” (warning: grammar terms and frameworks vary).
Passive: academy award nominated actor
Active: academy award winning writer
You can imagine these as reduced from relative clauses:
Passive: He is an actor who was nominated for an academy award [by the Academy].
Active: He is a writer who won an academy award.
If you “reduce” these relative clauses, you’ll be back to the start:
Passive: an actor who was nominated = a nominated actor (not a nominating actor)
Active: a writer who won = a winning actor (not a won actor)
See ThoughtCo’s Reduced Relative Clauses.
(We can talk about hyphens in another question.)
